# Facebook advertising: targeting for exact users

Tags: facebook, ads

Is it possible to target Facebook advertising for exact users?
For example: to show advertisements to all friends of a particular person?

Answer (score 1):

It's theoretically possible to narrow down the group to about 10-20 people if you know enough about your target's profile. However, targeting a particular user's friends is the kind of privacy violation that nobody wants. The only allowed kind of "friend targeting" is showing ads to friends of your current fans, e.g. "Your friend Jack likes this page".